# Can a journal article contain a personal circumstance description as motive for justifying the literature approach?

Tags: journals, writing

I was recently invited to have a paper published.

Unfortunately, a similar paper is about to be published on the practical/fun aspect of the project so I've had to re-frame the topic to focus on what we understand about the need for the project rather than the fun stuff itself.

The new paper required discussion on some aspects of psychology. I need to justify why I, as someone not in the field of psychology, felt capable of identifying it as a subject relevant to the discussion and presumably why I have slightly more than a fleeting grasp of the concepts. The gist is a long history of interacting with professionals on what defines my mental processes.

What would be the best way to say the discussion is best accompanied by an overview of the side subjects?

Comment: Why do you need to justify yourself? Are your results not strong enough to speak for themselves? Does anyone (outside of your direct team) even know your background?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold. Thanks for the response. The aspects are pretty well covered in the literature and I don't think there's anything controversial other than the journal is not remotely related to it. The aspects are entirely relevant, though. It's my first invitation and I'm worried about screwing it up. No one other than my team knows my background.

Comment: Is there really a need to re-frame? You could just publish without re-framing, perhaps mentioning that your work was conducted in parallel with the other.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I didn't want to just churn out a replica of the new work. I want to contribute something new, even if it is a fairly recent research topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit the article to a peer-reviewed journal, the reviewers should not (be able to) look at your academic history or status. If it gets accepted, the fact that it has been accepted shows that people think the findings are relevant for the field. There is no need to defend yourself in the text.

Furthermore, I would avoid any personal statements, especially if it concerns your own mental health, as it may jeopardise your career in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll avoid the caveat and see how it goes. Worse case, I guess, they ask for more information.